# Ampscript - Dynamic UTM parameters

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've figured out how to put in dynamic utm parameters to append to all links in an email with the below ampscript.

```
%%[
Var @campaign, @pcode
Set @campaignID = "%%campaignid%%"
Set @pcode = "%%pcode%%"
]%%
```

My question is - is there a way to add to the ampscript what to fill in for those parameters if those fields don't exist in a customers Profile Attribute.

For example if a customer doesn't have a '`pcode`' can i set a default in the ampscript?

Comment: Inside AMPScript Code blocks you should definitely not use stuff like this `Set @campaignID = "%%campaignid%%"`. When these fields are inside a dataexentension you would do it like this: `Set @campaignID = [campaignid]` if its a subscriber attribute you would use something like `Set @campaignID = AttributeValue(campaignid)`. But i guess it doesnt make any sense to store a campaignid in subscriber attributes :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use IF/ELSE statements. So, if in an AMPscript block, a rough example would be something like:

```
%%[
VAR @campaign, @pcode 

SET @pcode = pcode
SET @campaignID = campaignid

IF EMPTY(@pcode) == false THEN
    SET @pcode = pcode
ELSE
    SET @pcode = 'some default text here'
ENDIF
]%%

Output: %%=v(@pcode)=%%
```